# NetStream receiving events after being closed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, rtmp, netstream, wowza

I'm developing a one-on-one video chat application using Wowza. After the remote client stops publishing, I'm disconnecting the incoming NetStream. Here's a gist of my code:

```
incomingStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
incomingStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, incomingStreamHandler);
incomingStream.play("media");

private function incomingStreamHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    trace(event.info.code);
    if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify")
    {
        incomingStream.close();
        incomingStream.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, incomingStreamHandler);
        incomingStream = null;
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: after the NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify event fires and I close the incoming stream, I receive the following runtime error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

If I comment out the removeEventListener() line in incomingStreamHandler() above, I see that NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify is followed by NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound. **But why does this event still fire even after I close the incoming NetStream?**

(Initially, I was disconnecting the incoming stream on NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound instead of NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify but I found that the former event doesn't always fire so I want to rely on NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving:
incomingStream.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, incomingStreamHandler);

over
trace(event.info.code);

I hope it works...